# java.util.Vector - alternatives

Tags: java, vector, arraylist

Previously I would always have thought a Vector was good to use for non-descript objects when length was unknown.  As far as I was aware I thought it was thread-safe too

What would change that `Vector` shouldn't be used anymore, and what is the alternative?

Comment: It's curious that `Vector` has not been deprecated. I suppose since there is no one-for-one replacement, they haven't done so.

Comment: Note that this is also true of Hashtable--use HashMap instead.

Comment: @skaffman `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is more or less a one-for-one replacement insofar as it's a threadsafe `List` implementation. For most usages, `CopyOnWriteArrayList` should offer better performance than `Vector`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should use `ArrayList` instead of `Vector`. `Vector` used internal synchronisation, but that is rarely good enough for actual consistency, and only slows down execution when it is not really needed.

Also see [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-java-vector-class-is-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated).

Comment: Good point about rarely being "good enough for actual consistency." If a collection is visible to multiple threads, you should probably be using (and thoroughly understanding) the appropriate collection from `java.util.concurrent`. And if its not accessible to multiple threads, an `ArrayList` is cheaper. Eliminate grey areas where a collection "might be" used by multiple threads: you can't make a collection intrinsically thread-safe; how its clients use it is always a factor.

Comment: nowadays, do you know if Vector has been improved or if we must stick with ArrayList?

Comment: @AquariusPower The contract specifies that it needs to use synchronization, so it cannot really be improved. That said, a modern JVM will sometimes be able to remove the synchronization as an optimization, but in general, it is just better to use ArrayList.

Answer (score 16):

You can use an `ArrayList` instead.

If you need a synchronized version, you can do something like:

```
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();

List synchList = Collections.synchronizedList(arrayList);
```

Answer (score 8):

`ArrayList` is now the better class to use. `Vector` is now considered Legacy, and has the added performance overhead of being Thread-Safe.

Answer (score 7):

Use `ArrayList` when you need a `List` implementation but don't need thread safety, and use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` when you need a `List` implementation that is thread safe.

Comment: You need to have in mind that CopyOnWriteArrayList copy the whole array on mutative operations (add, remove ...). 
CopyOnWriteArrayList should only be used when traversal operations (get, iterate ...) vastly outnumber mutative operations.
Source : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html

Answer (score 6):

`Vector` is a legacy collection class from Java 1.0. In Java 1.2 (long ago!), the [Collections Framework](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html) was added which included new collection classes such as `ArrayList` and `HashMap`, which were intended to replace the legacy classes `Vector` and `Hashtable`.

As said before, the legacy collection classes had built-in synchronization, which is unnecessary for many applications. Synchronization has a performance overhead, so if it's not necessary, you shouldn't use it.

In some cases (when your program is multi-threaded, and multiple threads access the same data) you need to synchronize your collections. Some people would then use the old `Vector` or `Hashtable` classes, but a better way is to use a synchronization wrapper with for example an `ArrayList`:

```
// Your standard, unsynchronized list
List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

// Use this to put it into a synchronization wrapper
List<String> syncedData = Collections.synchronizedList(data);
```

See the API documentation of `Collections.synchronizedList()` (and other methods) for more information.

Comment: If you need a thread-safe List, CopyOnWriteArrayList offers better performance (in most cases) than Collections.synchronizedList(data)

Comment: @Dónal That's not really true.

Comment: @StefanReich please elaborate

Comment: CopyOnWriteArrayList copies the whole list on every change, so it can be incredibly slow if you change the list a lot.