# How to read from an array which is inside a vector?

Tags: java, arrays, vector

I know how to access an array at point i, and how to access a vector at point i, but I can't figure out how to access an array which is inside a vector. I'm basically looking for code which does this:

```
  Vector.get(0).[i];
```

(So access point i of the array which is in the first point of the vector)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No `.` (period):

```
vector.get(0)[i];
```

*Note: Use `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` instead of `Vector` (see this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792134/a-colleague-said-dont-use-java-util-vector-anymore-why-not) for details).*

---

Example:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Vector<String[]> vector = new Vector<String[]>();
    vector.add(new String[] {"Hello", "World!"});

    System.out.println(vector.get(0)[1]); // prints World!
}
```