# How to initialize List<String> object in Java?

Tags: java, list

I can not initialize a List as in the following code:

```
List<String> supplierNames = new List<String>();
supplierNames.add("sup1");
supplierNames.add("sup2");
supplierNames.add("sup3");
System.out.println(supplierNames.get(1));
```

I face the following error:

> Cannot instantiate the type `List<String>`

How can I instantiate `List<String>`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a new List in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858572/how-to-make-a-new-list-in-java)

Answer (score 887, accepted):

If you check the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) for `List` you'll notice it says:

```
Interface List<E>
```

Being an `interface` means it cannot be instantiated (no `new List()` is possible).

If you check that link, you'll find some `class`es that implement `List`:

> All Known Implementing Classes:
>
> `AbstractList`, `AbstractSequentialList`, `ArrayList`, `AttributeList`, `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, `LinkedList`, `RoleList`, `RoleUnresolvedList`, `Stack`, `Vector`

Some of those can be instantiated (the ones that are not defined as `abstract class`). Use their links to know more about them, I.E: to know which fits better your needs.

The 3 most commonly used ones probably are:

```
 List<String> supplierNames1 = new ArrayList<String>();
 List<String> supplierNames2 = new LinkedList<String>();
 List<String> supplierNames3 = new Vector<String>();
```

---

Bonus:
You can also instantiate it with values, in an easier way, using the `Arrays` `class`, as follows:

```
List<String> supplierNames = Arrays.asList("sup1", "sup2", "sup3");
System.out.println(supplierNames.get(1));
```

But note you are not allowed to add more elements to that list, as it's `fixed-size`.

Comment: Arrays.asList is great but as you should have noticed by now fails to do what one expects in cases like `int[] a = {1,2,3}; System.out.println(Arrays.asList(a)); // [[I@70cdd2]`

Comment: @J.A.I.L. That's not what's happening. That's a list of one element, where the one element is an array of ints. The wanted behaviour was probably a list of three elements 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: @Christoffer Hammarström to print a list or an array, you could use java.util.Arrays.toString(array);, so this feature is already given..

Comment: @Maxr1998 I don't know what you're talking about, i meant that `[I@70cdd2` is the `.toString()` of an array of ints, not the memory address of a `List` like @J.A.I.L. said.

Comment: @Christopher Hammarström toString prints the memory address.

Comment: My method prints the content.

Comment: Some discorage use of Vector like [this](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=65) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792134/a-colleague-said-dont-use-java-util-vector-anymore-why-not). Because of threading issues

Comment: If you need the resulting list to be an `ArrayList`, use `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("sup1", "sup2", "sup3"))`

Comment: I have a method that returns `List<String>` to a `List<String>` working correctly. Anyone know how this is possible?
`List<String> tableList = getTableNames(sqlString);`

Comment: @DanielF By default, the Arrays.asList method returns an ArrayList, there is no need to explicitly convert it to ArrayList

Comment: @AkhilBaby It returns a `List<T>` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...) see https://www.baeldung.com/java-arrays-aslist-vs-new-arraylist

Comment: @DanielF It is actually returning an ArrayList, but not java.util.ArrayList :)  The returned one is an instance of java.util.Arrays.ArrayList - which is essentially a list backed by the immutable array

Answer (score 203):

Can't instantiate an interface but there are few implementations:

**JDK2**

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");
```

**JDK7**

```
//diamond operator
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("one");
list.add("two");
list.add("three");
```

**JDK8**

```
List<String> list = Stream.of("one", "two", "three").collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**JDK9**

```
// creates immutable lists, so you can't modify such list 
List<String> immutableList = List.of("one", "two", "three");

// if we want mutable list we can copy content of immutable list 
// to mutable one for instance via copy-constructor (which creates shallow copy)
List<String> mutableList = new ArrayList<>(List.of("one", "two", "three"));
```

Plus there are lots of other ways supplied by other libraries like **Guava**.

```
List<String> list = Lists.newArrayList("one", "two", "three");
```

Answer (score 43):

List is an *Interface*, you cannot instantiate an Interface, because interface is a convention, what methods should have your classes. In order to instantiate, you need some realizations(implementations) of that interface. Try the below code with very popular implementations of List interface:

```
List<String> supplierNames = new ArrayList<String>();
```

or

```
List<String> supplierNames = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Answer (score 18):

You will need to use `ArrayList<String>` or such.

`List<String>` is an interface.

Use this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

...

List<String> supplierNames = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 15):

List is an interface, and you can not initialize an interface. Instantiate an implementing class instead.

Like:

```
List<String> abc = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> xyz = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Answer (score 11):

In most cases you want simple `ArrayList` - an implementation of `List`

Before JDK version 7

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

JDK 7 and later you can use the diamond operator

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Further informations are written here [Oracle documentation - Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections)

Answer (score 9):

List is just an interface, a definition of some generic list. You need to provide an implementation of this list interface. Two most common are:

**ArrayList** - a list implemented over an array

```
List<String> supplierNames = new ArrayList<String>();
```

**LinkedList** - a list implemented like an interconnected chain of elements

```
List<String> supplierNames = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Answer (score 7):

Depending on what kind of List you want to use, something like

```
List<String> supplierNames = new ArrayList<String>();
```

should get you going.

List is the interface, ArrayList is one implementation of the List interface. More implementations that may better suit your needs can be found by reading the [JavaDocs of the List interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to create an **immutable** `List<T>` with only **one** object in it, you can use this API:

```
List<String> oneObjectList = Collections.singletonList("theOnlyObject”);
```

More info: [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List))

Answer (score 5):

List is an Interface . You cant use List to initialize it.

```
  List<String> supplierNames = new ArrayList<String>();
```

These are the some of List impelemented classes,

```
ArrayList, LinkedList, Vector
```

You could use any of this as per your requirement. These each classes have its own features.

Comment: Some discorage use of Vector like [this](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=65) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792134/a-colleague-said-dont-use-java-util-vector-anymore-why-not). Because of threading issues

Answer (score 3):

Just in case, any one still lingering around this question. Because, i see one or two new users again asking the same question and everyone telling then , *No you can't do that, Dear Prudence*, Apart from all the answers given here, I would like to provide additional Information - 
Yes you can actually do, **List list = new List();**
But at the cost of writing implementations of all the methods of Interfaces. 
The notion is not simply List list = new List(); but

```
List<Integer> list = new List<Integer>(){

        @Override
        public int size() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean contains(Object o) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
```

..... and So on (Cant write all methods.)

This is an example of **Anonymous class**. Its correct when someone states , **No you cant instantiate an interface,** and that's right. But you can never say , **You CANT write List list = new List();** but, evidently you can do that and that's a hard statement to make *that You can't do*.

Comment: To be clear though, this doesn't create an object whose actual type is `List`. Rather, it declares a new class which has no name and implements `List`, and at run-time creates a new object of the newly-declared class.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of :

```
List<String> supplierNames = new List<String>();
```

Write this if you are using latest JDK:

```
 List<String> supplierNames = new ArrayList<>();
```

It's the correct way of initializing a List.

Answer (score 0):

We created [soyuz-to](https://github.com/thedocs-io/soyuz-to) to simplify 1 problem: how to convert `X` to `Y` (e.g. `String` to `Integer`). Constructing of an object is also kind of conversion so it has a simple function to construct `Map`, `List`, `Set`:

```java
import io.thedocs.soyuz.to;

List<String> names = to.list("John", "Fedor");
```

Please check it - it has a lot of other useful features