# How can I initialize a collection and add data on the same line?

Tags: java

In C# I can create a collection of some kind and initialize it with data on the same line.

`var foo = new List<string> {"one","two","three"};`

Is there an equivalent way to do this in Java?

Comment: Comments from the downvoter?

Comment: likely because there are many duplicates of this question which are easily searchable.

Comment: I did search. for some reason nothing popped up. I'll remove it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395114/how-to-initialize-liststring-object-in-java

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you need a **read-only** `List`

```
List<String> numbers = Arrays.asList("one","two","three");

// Can't add since the list is immutable
numbers.add("four"); // java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

If you would like to **modify** the `List` later on.

```
List<String> numbers2 = new ArrayList<String>(
                            Arrays.asList("one","two","three"));
numbers2.add("four");

System.out.println(numbers2); // [one, two, three, four]
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `Arrays.asList` produces a **MUTABLE** list. The documentations indicates that the resulting list has a fixed size but `numbers.set(0, "one")` will absolutely modify both the list and underlying array.

Comment: For interface driven people.........this will work too:     Collection<MyObject> inlineCollection = Arrays.asList( myObjectInstantiatedOne, myObjectInstantiatedTwo, myObjectInstantiatedThree );        Thanks for this answer Ravi!

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`Arrays.asList(T... a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)

```
List<String> foo = Arrays.asList("one","two","three");
```

As Boris mentions in the comments the resulting `List` is immutable (ie. read-only). You will need to convert it to an `ArrayList` or similar in order to modify the collection:

```
List<String> foo = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("one","two","three"));
```

You can also create the `List` using an anonymous subclass and initializer:

```
List<String> foo = new ArrayList<String>() {
    {
        add("one");
        add("two");
        add("three");
    }
};
```

Comment: This makes the the resulting List immutable.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer doing this using the Guava (formerly called Google Collections) library, which both removes the need to write the type down again AND has all kinds of ways of adding data straight away.

Example: `List<YourClass> yourList = Lists.newArrayList();`

Or with adding data: `List<YourClass> yourList = Lists.newArrayList(yourClass1, yourclass2);`

The same works for all other kinds of collections and their various implementations. Another example: `Set<String> treeSet = Sets.newTreeSet();`

You can find it at https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

Answer (score 1):

The best that I've been able to come up with is:

```
final List<String> foo = new ArrayList<String>() {{
  add("one");
  add("two");
  add("three");
}};
```

Basically, that says that you are creating an anonymous sub-class of the `ArrayList` class which is then statically initialized using `"one", "two", "three"`.

Comment: This question is intended for Java.

Comment: There is no reason to create an anonymous class to avoid a few lines of code.

Comment: sorry, I've been working on a little too much javascript lately.

Comment: `List` is an interface in Java

Comment: Yeah, I guess that the anonymous implementation would require you to also implement all of the other `List` methods. Better to anonymously extend a concrete implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("one","two","three")
```

Comment: This makes the the resulting `List` immutable.

Comment: Ok then `new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three"))`

Comment: Now you've created a list and an array as well as the list wrapper for the array when all that was required was an array...

Comment: Create a static factory method or, if you're using Guava, there are plenty of methods there.

Comment: That's not plain java 'inline' solutions. Generally I'm using Guava too.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> numbers = Arrays.asList("one","two","three");
```

As Boris commented, it makes your `numbers` immutable.

Yes,You can, but with two lines.

```
List<String> numbers= new ArrayList<String>();
Collections.addAll(numbers,"one","two","three");
```

If you still want in Only in one line ,With [Gauva](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)

```
List<String> numbers= Lists.newArrayList("one","two","three");
```