# Transform HashMap<String, String> to HashMap<String, List<String>>()

Tags: java, android, android-listview, hashmap

I have this code,

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> eventosList;

     HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            contact.put("id", id);
                            contact.put("name", name);

eventosList.add(contact);
```

Is it possible to transform this `HashMap<String, String> contact` to `HashMap<String, List<String>>() contact`? How can I do this? Thank you so much

Comment: You are wanting something like this?   HashMap<String, List<String>> contact = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

Comment: I am wanting something like this HashMap<String, List<String>>() but I have this HashMap<String, String>

Comment: Can you plz make more clear? why your trying this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, List<String>>> eventosList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, List<String>>>();
HashMap<String, List<String>> contact = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("1");
list.add("2");
contact.put("id", list);
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
list1.add("Mohammed");
list1.add("Ali");
contact.put("name", list1);
eventosList.add(contact);
```

Also Note as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13395114/3879470): List is an INTERFACE, and you cannot Initialize an Interface, so use any of its implementing classes like Arraylist, Vector, LinkedList, AbstractList, AbstractSequentialList, AttributeList,  etc, to initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, List<String>>> eventosList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, List<String>>>();

    HashMap<String, List<String>> contact = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    contact.put("id", list1);
    contact.put("name", list2);

    eventosList.add(contact);
```