# How can I initialize a List<Record> Object in java

Tags: java

the return type is List and I declare list for returning and how can I actually declare it after new?

```
public List<Record> findClosestRecords(int n) throws IndexException {
    if (!sorted || n > records.size()) {

    }
    List<Record> list = new ;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        Record r = this.records.get(i);
        list.add(i, r);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: List<Record> list = new ArrayList()<Record>;

Comment: List is an interface, you need to create an object which implements the interface. Duplicate of: [How to initialize List<String> object in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395114/how-to-initialize-liststring-object-in-java)

Comment: This questions has duplicate written all over it.

Answer (score 5):

You can try like this:

```
List<Record> list = new ArrayList<Record>();
```

Note that List is an interface and you cannot initialize an interface. So you need to create an object which implements the List interface.

Answer (score 2):

You have to instantiate a concrete implementation of the List interface. The most common one is ArrayList but you can find others in the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

```
List<Record> list = new ArrayList<Record>();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Record> list = new ArrayList<Record>();
```

or use diamond syntax;

```
List<Record> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is implying you implemented the List interface by means of an ArrayList.