# Casting List<String> to a String return type

Tags: java, string, list, class, casting

The method (below) is a `List<String>` type and the class that I'm using as a parameter is a `String`. I was wondering if the way I'm casting would work:

```
return (List<String>) subList;
```

This is the method:

```
public List<String> getWords(String phrase) {
    LetterCounter subList = new LetterCounter(phrase);
    if (phrase == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    for (String element : dict) {
        if (subList.contains(element))
            subList.add(element);
    }
    return (List<String>) subList;
}// End of getWords
```

This URL points to the `LetterCounter` class:

http://pastebin.com/XbeUSvPx

I put it in paste bin because the class is too long.

Comment: Can you show the LetterCounter definition, please?

Comment: Hi @JorgeCampos I just updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better creating new instance of `List<String>` and adding String element to that like,

```
public List<String> getWords(String phrase) {
    LetterCounter subList = new LetterCounter(phrase);
    if (phrase == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
     List<String> str = new List<>();
    for (String element : dict) {
        if (subList.contains(element))
            str.add(element);
    }
    return str;
}
```

I'm suggesting this, because Your `element` in loop is `String`.

Comment: Yes thats better but it doesn't respond the question.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna I think this would work! But there was an error in how the List<String> str was declared though. I changed it to: **List<String> str;** instead

Comment: @Ani That's because your one may not be java 8. So that you got that warning. It's simple. Declare that as IDE suggests you.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna ok - I see. Thanks for the help! ^^

Comment: @ShreeKrishna it seems right - however I'm getting a Dereference possible null pointer at **str.add(element);** for **"add"**

Comment: It's may be because you have not written the full statement like `List<String> str = new List<String>();` May be you've wrote `List<String> str = null` or only `List<String> str`; Fix that. and May be better creating it as a class variable.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna I looked up the way to initialize a List<String> **[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395114/how-to-initialize-liststring-object-in-java)** and changed  it to **List<String> str = new ArrayList<>();** and now it's working!

Comment: @Ani Haha ohh... Thats great !! Actually it should be ArrayList or any subclass of List. I directly wrote it in editor so that, it happened, But you got concept. thats great..

Answer (score 1):

If the definition of `LetterCounter` class is as follows:

```
public class LetterCounter extends ArrayList<String>{
        // implementation

}
```

You do not need to cast at all. This is because Java allows covariant return type. Please look at [What is a covariant return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882584/what-is-a-covariant-return-type)