# Add elements to a list and separate each element by a colon ":" instead of a comma

Tags: java

I have the below three elements :

```
play_full_NAME=556677

pause_full_NAME=9922

stop_full_NAME=112233
```

A string `"abc"` returns all the above three elements one by one from a particular piece of code.

I am trying to add all three elements in a list separated by a colon ":"

Sample output :

```
play_full_NAME=556677:pause_full_NAME=9922:stop_full_NAME=112233
```

My attempt:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.join(":",abc)
```

Please help with a better way to handle this.

Comment: _A string "abc" returns all the above three elements one by one_ — What does this mean?

Comment: A better way? Your current attempt won't even compile.

Comment: @khelwood . I am running a loop which returns the elements one by one.My aim is to store them in a list where each element gets separated by a colon ":"

Comment: @Thanks for the response. I am searching for a way to  store them in a list where each element gets separated by a colon ":"

Comment: Can I ask why do you need to add a `String` ":"` between each instance in that `List` ? Seems an odd requirements to be honest. If this is to print the list later. Simply add the `:` when you print the `List` between each element, not in the list itself.

Comment: Lists don't store separators. The output would depend on the code that gives an output? I may be confused.

Comment: Why would you think the `list.add(":", abc)` works? Did you check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)? There is no such method in the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Did you really understood the [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) well?
>
> In fact, there is no separator, each item / value is stored as different "object".

So you have some amount of independent values- Strings in this case, what can you see on screenshot bellow, or if you will do `System.out.println(someList);` it will call override of method [`toString()` which is inherited from `Object` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) , which is root parent class of all classes in Java.

[image]

So its absolutely nonsense to add some split character between each items in `List`, they are split already, you can access each item by [`get(int position)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-) method.

So if you want to print each item of list "by yourself", can be done like follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < someList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(i + " = " + someList.get(i));    
}
/* output will be 
   1 = 1 item
   2 = 2 item
   3 = 3 item
   4 = 4 item
*/
```

If you want to implement custom method for printing "your list" then you can extend eg. `ArrayList` class and override `toString` method, but better and more trivial approach will be prepare some method in some utils to get formatted String output with context of List- eg. *(notice there will be `;` after last element)*

```
public static String getFormatStringFromList(ArrayList<String> data) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        sb.append(data.get(i) + ";");   
    }

    return sb.toString();
    //eg. 0 item;1 item;2 item;3 item;4 item;
}
```

To avoid last separator you can do eg. simple check

```
public static String getFormatStringFromListWitoutLastSeparator(List<String> someList) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < someList.size(); i++) {
            sb.append(someList.get(i));
            if(i < someList.size() -1) {
                 sb.append(";");
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
        //0 item;1 item;2 item;3 item;4 item
        /*
           someList[0] = 0 item
           someList[1] = ;
           someList[2] = 1 item
           someList[3] = ;
           {etc..}
        */
    }
```

> The best approach to get String from list will be like @krisnik advised:
>
> `String joinedString = String.join(":", list);`

Comment: Good explanation (you should add the output for the first code) but check [krisnik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49979321/4391450) to see how to correclty add a separator. Your solution adds one to many separator by the way.

Comment: @AxelH hey, thanks, I added some more clues :) And yes, you are also correct, this is working , but totally not the best approach, just for demonstration to understand

Comment: I personally prefer to remove the last character at the end with `sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1)` to remove the last character. That allow me to remove the condition in the loop ;) Just need to check if there is at least one item in the list (at the start).

Comment: hehe :D many ways, but for sure `setLength` will be more effective

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping !!

Comment: @JAne check also @krisnik solution, its better for creating separated string from `Array` or `List`

Answer (score 12):

Your understanding about `List` is little flawed. Comma is only printed for representation purposes.

To join strings with colon, you can do the following

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("play_full_NAME=556677", 
                                  "pause_full_NAME=9922", 
                                  "stop_full_NAME=112233");

String joinedString = String.join(":", list);
```

Comment: thanks for the response. But the value of the three elements is not static.Its a dynamic value.So cant hard code the value. I have already looked at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395114/how-to-initialize-liststring-object-in-java

Comment: Yes. This will work for any dynamic list. Can you please share in which way you are expecting your input?

Comment: The intersting part is the [`String.join(CharSequence delimiter, Iterable<? extends CharSequence> elements)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-) method @Jane. This could use some explanations but this is a good answer.

Comment: Thanks for the effort !!

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add the colon elements separately if you want them to be within your list.

For example:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add(abc);
list.add(":");
list.add(def);
list.add(":");
```

and so on.

I would recommend against this, however, as you can simply format the output string using `String.format` or a `StringBuilder` when you need it.

Comment: I am up voting just because you were willing to help.Thanks.God bless