# How to initialize List Of List in one line

Tags: java, list, arraylist

How can I initialize a `List` Of `Lists` in one line?

```
List<List<Integer>> list = .....;
```

Comment: There's a very complete answer over here already: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47288158/236528

Comment: What do you want to initialise it to?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
List<List<Integer>> list = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1,2), Arrays.asList(3,4));
```

In Java 9+ you can replace `Arrays.asList()` with `List.of()`:

```
List<List<Integer>> list = List.of(List.of(1,2), List.of(3,4));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<List<Integer>> list = 
    Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1,2,3), Arrays.asList(4,5,6));
```

Comment: Why so defensive?

Comment: @shmosel what do you mean?

Comment: Why do you need to copy it to a `new ArrayList`?

Comment: edited, thanks! @shmosel