# Vector is an obsolete Collection

Tags: java, vector, obsolete

> The Inspection reports any uses of java.util.Vector or java.util.hashtable. While still supported, these classes were made obsolete by the JDK 1.2 Collection classes and should probably not be used in new Development....

I have a project in Java which uses [vector](/questions/tagged/vector) Everywhere, and I'm using JDK 8 which is the latest one. I want to know if I can run that application on latest java.

And tell if i can use some other keyword for ArrayList like Vector for new java.

Comment: java.util.Vector is available in java 8 for backward compatibility.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792134/a-colleague-said-dont-use-java-util-vector-anymore-why-not

Comment: *"And tell if i can use some other keyword for ArrayList like Vector for new java."* -  I have no idea what you are asking here ...

Comment: @StephenC yeah wrong question ..i almost forgot [tag:ArrayList] is itself a keyword  ooops confused min...this project keep me wobbling..;)

Comment: Erm ... that still makes no sense.  `arraylist` is not a Java keyword.  It is an identifier.

Comment: it's a defined class in java so yeah

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, although `Vector` is mostly obsoleted by `ArrayList`, it is still perfectly legal to use, and your project should run just fine.

As noted, however, it is not recommended to use. The main reason for this is that all of its methods are `synchronized`, which is usually useless and could considerably slow down your application. Any local variable that's not shared outside the scope of the method can safely be replaced with an `ArrayList`. Method arguments, return values and data members should be inspected closely before being replaced with `ArrayList`, lest you unwittingly change the synchronization semantics and introduce a hard-to-discover bug.

Comment: Thank you @Mureinik ..and please tell me if i can use [tag:ServerSocket] at the client site?