# How to create vector list or array of list in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, vector

I want to create vector array like this in c++ in Java

```
vector<int> tab_u[255]
```

I don't have idea how to fast create. I try this:

```
List<Integer> tab[] = new List[255];
```

but i cant add something

i want something like this

```
[0] = {1,2,2,3}
[1] = {2,3}
[2] = {1}
```

Comment: Vector<Integer> vector = new Vector<Integer>(255)

Comment: ArrayList<String> cars = new ArrayList<String>(255);

Comment: A quick look at [oracle guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html) could save you from embarrassing situations like this one.

Comment: ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> cars = new ArrayList<>(255);

Answer (score 2):

you can defined as;

```
Vector<Integer> vector = new Vector();
```

but as you may read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275933/vector-is-an-obsolete-collection): vectors are kind of old...

[Vector is an obsolete Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275933/vector-is-an-obsolete-collection)

and maybe you should consider using another collection like an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ArrayList<String> cars = new ArrayList<String>();

cars.add("Volvo");
cars.add("BMW");
cars.add("Ford");
cars.add("Mazda");
System.out.println(cars);
```

I dont remember vectors in java but this is very similar. Hope it helps.

Comment: To make clear you are using an `interface` and a special implementation of it, you could have written `List<String> cars = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Yes, thats true!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some additional work, because array initialization and array element initialization are separated.

```
List<Integer> myIntegerVectors = new List[255];  // Array initialized
for(int i = 0;i < myIntegerVectors.length; i++)  // Elements initialized in loop
    myIntegerVectors[i] = new ArrayList<>();

myIntegerVectors[7].add(1337);
```