# .next() is not working in ResultSet in Java

Tags: java, database, netbeans, resultset

.next() is not working in this code. I tried a lot but in vain. For example, if I have 10 rows in branch_issuance_g_item_vise (DB table name). This code prints 10 times the first row only.

```
void stockIssuance(String date) throws SQLException{
    report_table.setVisible(true);
    
    Statement s = db.conn().createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM branch_issuance_g_item_vise");
    
    DefaultTableModel dt = (DefaultTableModel) report_table.getModel();
    dt.setRowCount(0);
    
    Vector v = new Vector();
    if(!rs.next()){
        m.printError("No Data Found");
        rs.beforeFirst();
    }
    else{
        while(rs.next()){
            v.add(rs.getString("item_name"));
            v.add(rs.getString("qty"));

            dt.addRow(v);
        }
    }
}
```

Even, this is not working.

```
void stockIssuance(String date) throws SQLException{
    report_table.setVisible(true);
    
    Statement s = db.conn().createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM branch_issuance_g_item_vise");
    
    DefaultTableModel dt = (DefaultTableModel) report_table.getModel();
    dt.setRowCount(0);
    
    Vector v = new Vector();
    while(rs.next()){
        v.add(rs.getString("item_name"));
        v.add(rs.getString("qty"));

        dt.addRow(v);
    }
}
```

Comment: try to remove the `if(!rs.next())`. Just keep the while loop.

Comment: I tried, but the same result.

Comment: The logic of that `if` will cause it to skip a line. And you keep using the same vector. So you are actually updating all its previous instances. You have to use a new Vector in each iteration.

Comment: The second code block is what you should use, but you need to move the `Vector v = new Vector();` statement *inside* the `while` loop, so each call to `addRow()` adds a different vector object. Same as described in the [duplicate link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843506/why-does-my-arraylist-contain-n-copies-of-the-last-item-added-to-the-list) up top.

Comment: @RealSkeptic thanks a lot brother. Can you please explain, why It needs to create a new Vector Object in every iteration?

Answer (score 0):

You should ceate a new vector v at the start of the while loop. As is, the rows will be appended to the vector but you only have two columns.

Furthermore, every time you call rs.next the resultset is advanced one step. Easiest fix would be to remove the check if the resultset is empty.

Comment: Not clear. Use a new vector. Clearing it will just have the same effect but end up with a shorter vector.

Comment: Clearing the vector is equally wrong to what the code is currently doing

Comment: The same code is working well in my other Project. But I don't know, what wrong is there.

Comment: Updated the answer. You are completely right, a new vector is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Add [rs.beforeFirst](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#beforeFirst--) before `while`, and move the <strike>Vector</strike> [ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792134/java-util-vector-alternatives) creation inside loop

```
else {
    rs.beforeFirst();
    while(rs.next()) {
       ArrayList v = new ArrayList();
```

> Moves the cursor to the front of this ResultSet object, just before the first row. This method has no effect if the result set contains no rows.

> You should use ArrayList instead of Vector

Comment: This is not the main problem. It merely skips one line. The real problem is reusing the vector.

Comment: @RealSkeptic true, updated

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should call `res.beforeFirst()` before the else condition, because everytime the if statements checks the condition, you are doing `rs.next()` and when you are doing else condition you are skipping the first element by doing `rs.next()` again.

To solve your problem, I suggest you to do something like this, without using a vector:

```
ResultSet res=stat.executeQuery(query);
        while (res.next()){
            model.setRowCount(model.getRowCount() + 1);
            int currentRow = model.getRowCount() - 1;
            model.setValueAt(res.getString("param1"), currentRow, 0);
            model.setValueAt(res.getString("param2"), currentRow, 1);
            model.setValueAt(res.getString("param3"), currentRow, 2);
            model.setValueAt(res.getString("param4"), currentRow, 3);
            
        }
```

In this example I'm using a row counter and I have 4 fields, like "Name|Surname|Date|ID|" that's why you see 0,1,2,3. If you just have one column in your Table, just use

```
model.setValueAt(res.getString("something"), currentRow, 0);
```

If you keep want to use your vector, you need to init it everytime in the while loop:

```
Vector v;
while(rs.next()){
   v=new Vector();
   .....
}
```

Comment: Else is not skipping the first row. I have 10 rows in the table it prints the first row 10 times.

Comment: Edited without vector.